# LCD interfacing with stm8

Tags: c

I'm trying to interface a 16x2 LCD with the stm8l. I'm done the initialization part. Is there a data register analogous to the USART_DR register where data to be displayed on the lcd is written? Also do I have to write a function to convert all the 26 alphabets and 10 digits to their respective ASCII values separately or the lcd controller does it on its own? Here's the initialization part:

```
void lcdinit(void)
{
LCD_CR1 = 0X06;
LCD_CR2 = 0X26;
LCD_FRQ = 0X00;
LCD_CR3 = 0X00;
LCD_PM0 = 0XFF;
LCD_PM1 = 0XFF;
LCD_PM2 = 0XFF;
LCD_CR3 = 1<<6;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation? It should be there how you write to the display. How else did you find out how to initialize the display?

Comment: I read the data sheet of the stm8l and initialized control registers accordingly. But they haven't mentioned about writing to the display.Here's the link to the datasheet: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/2e/3b/8c/8f/60/af/4b/2c/CD00218714.pdf/files/CD00218714.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00218714.pdf

Comment: How about experimenting with the "LCD display memory (LCD_RAM)"?

Comment: The question is too broad. This would entirely depend on the type of the LCD. Most often they use SPI but UART or parallel are also common. Or does this particular STM have a display driver on-chip?

Comment: We are not a tutoring site, nor a datasheet repo.

Comment: @ABHI: You seem to be attempting to interface a character LCD module with the built-in LCD driver of your MCU. This won't work, this part has insufficient columns/rows to address such a screen and more to the point the module will its own built-in driver to use. The end result will likely be something along the lines of writing ASCII characters to a data register, though not knowing the specific part and schematic it is impossible to offer any details.

Comment: Umm.. when @Someprogrammerdude commented 'Maybe you should read the documentation?' - s/he meant the LCD display module docs, not anything to do with your controller.  If the LCD module has a controller itself, (black epoxy blobs on back of PCB), then you are in for some fun.

Comment: Have you checked on web for any tutorials? [Here](https://www.8051projects.net/lcd-interfacing/introduction.php) is one such tutorial.

Comment: @doynax I'm using the GDM0801 lcd module. I tried to pass characters to the LCD_RAMx registers and I found that the corresponding ASCII values of the characters I pass get stored properly. How should I obtain the output on the display

Comment: @AHBI: That module has a 4 or 8-bit parallel interface which you will want to bit-bang through the I/O ports of your MCU. The details will depend on the schematic of your PCB. The built-in LCD controller and its registers accessed in the are _not_ involved however.